# Do I need to get a device certified by the FCC if it uses the ESP32/8266?

Tags: wifi, esp8266, fcc, emissions

I plan on making a device that the user can control with their phone via a WiFi connection to an ESP8266 or ESP32. If I end up selling this device, will I need to get it certified?

The ESP32/8266 has an FCC ID written on it. Does this count, or do I need an FCC ID for my device? I don't plan on selling more than 100 of them, so it would be too expensive for me to get it tested.

Does the answer to this question depend on whether I:
Use an external antenna?
Use a readily available ESP breakout board?
Design the ESP directly into my board?

Comment: This should answer your question https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/16935/things-to-watch-out-when-applying-fcc-ce?rq=1

Comment: That question doesn't answer the question adequately IMO